# ivy:buildnumber fails against Artifactory if file extension/type is not .jar

Tags: ant, ivy, artifactory

I am experimenting with Ivy 2.3.0, Artifactory 3.0.3 and Ant. The problem is that I cannot set ivy:buildnumber to work against a Artifactory repo if the extension of the file I have using is not .jar. It works fine against my local one. When I try it against Artifactory if fails to set the buildnumber. Running Ant with -debug I get the following output:

```
Setting project property: ivy.version -> 2.3.0
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in ${http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/].
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml].
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.md5].
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.sha1].
[ivy:buildnumber]               found 4 resources
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/testmod-20130814190841.pl].
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/testmod-20130814190841.pl.md5].
[ivy:buildnumber] ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/testmod-20130814190841.pl.sha1].
[ivy:buildnumber]               found 3 urls
[ivy:buildnumber]               0 matched http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/[artifact]-20130814190841.jar
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml
[ivy:buildnumber] HTTP response status: 404 url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml/
[ivy:buildnumber] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml/
[ivy:buildnumber] problem while listing resources in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml with oe:
[ivy:buildnumber]   java.io.IOException The HTTP response code for http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml/ did not indicate a success. See log for more detail.
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.md5
[ivy:buildnumber]               found 0 urls
[ivy:buildnumber]               0 matched http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.md5/[artifact]-ivy-20130814190841.xml.md5.jar
[ivy:buildnumber]       using oe to list all in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.sha1
[ivy:buildnumber]               found 0 urls
[ivy:buildnumber]               0 matched http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/ivy-20130814190841.xml.sha1/[artifact]-ivy-20130814190841.xml.sha1.jar
Setting project property: ivy.new.revision -> 0
Setting project property: ivy.new.build.number -> 0
Property "ivy.build.number" has not been set
  [echo] new.rev: working@Win7Dev 0 ${ivy.build.number} 0
```

Critical line seems to be:

```
[ivy:buildnumber]               0 matched http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/com/testorg/testmod/20130814190841/[artifact]-20130814190841.jar
```

If the file is a .jar file this says '1 matched...' and the buildnumber is set. If, on the other hand, it is something else, such as .zip, it fails, as shown above.

The definition of the item in the ivy.xml file is:

```
<publications>
  <artifact name="testmod" ext="zip" type="zip"/>
</publications>
```

In Artifactory I created a repo with a maven-2-default layout and contains testmod.

My Ant target contains:

```
<ivy:info/>

<ivy:buildnumber resolver="oe" organisation="${ivy.organisation}" module="${ivy.module}"/>

<echo>new.rev: ${ivy.revision} ${ivy.new.revision} ${ivy.build.number} ${ivy.new.build.number}</echo>
```

The oe resolver is defined as follows:

```
<url name="oe" m2compatible="true" >
  <ivy pattern="${http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
  <artifact pattern="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>      
</url>
```

The debug output and result is the same if I use an ibiblio resolver defined as follows:

```
<ibiblio name="oe1" m2compatible="true" root="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo" useMavenMetadata="false"/>
```

The module in the Artifactory repo got there using a Jenkins Artifactory plugin. This using:

```
Ivy pattern: [organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml 
Artifact pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was stuck on the same problem. Looks like I'll be going with a workaround with separate ivy settings for non-jar artifacts so that I can hard code the extension. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that extensions with 2 chars are not picked by artifactory, it has to have at least 3 chars.... I also do not understand why.